# SQL/JPQL select, count and sum distinct results from table with hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jpql

I am working with two tables, `users` and `accounts`, which are linked to the `User` and `Account` java entities.
`user` entries are in a hierarchical structure: user -> manager -> admin
User can have accounts, managers and admins cannot, the hierarchy is established by `supervisor_id`, in this case: user.supervisor_id = manager.id, manager.supervisor_id = admin.id. Each user entry also has a `role` column showing their roles, i.e. user.role = 'user', manager.role = 'manager', admin.role = 'admin'

Account to user relation is established by:
account.user_id = user.id, each user can have multiple accounts. `accounts` table also has a `balance` column.

And here is what I am trying to do, from the admin side, I would like to view the number of user's accounts, as well as the total number of account balance as a simple statistic.

The JPQL query I used is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(acct.id), COALESCE(SUM(acct.balance),0)
FROM Account acct, User user, User manager, User admin
WHERE user.supervisor_id = manager.id AND manager.supervisor_id = admin.id
AND admin.id = :adminId AND acct.user_id = user.id
```

:adminId is the id of the admin as a parameter. This query seems to retrieve data from duplicate results, and adding "AND" conditions like "user.role = 'user'" does not seem to work. What is causing this query to return duplicate results and how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Edit:
Found some mistakes on my part: I forgot something, a user can be directly under admin, that is why I changed the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(acct.id), COALESCE(SUM(acct.balance),0)
FROM Account acct, User user, User manager, User admin
WHERE (user.supervisor_id = manager.id AND manager.supervisor_id = admin.id
OR user.supervisor_id = admin.id)
AND admin.id = :adminId AND acct.user_id = user.id
```

Problem still exists.

Comment: You don't seem to have a join condition between `Account` and `User`.. maybe `WHERE acct.user_id = user.id`.
Personally I prefer to use the standard `JOIN` syntax as errors like this are easier to spot.

Comment: @Arth thanks, I left out the last part when copying the query. Just edited the query part, but the problem still exist though...

Comment: hmm.. looks OK to me, next step would be to `SELECT *` and try and figure it out from there.

Comment: @Arth I am not familiar with JOIN syntax in JPQL, doesn't it behave similarly with "="?

Comment: I don't know JPQL, but you tagged this questions as MySQL and SQL-Server.. I suggest you remove those tags. As a side note.. you should only  get 1 result anyway, no duplicates.

Comment: @Arth the DB is MySQL. And I tried using the query directly on the server, and it returns duplicates still.